# SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode: subscriptions failing

Tags: permissions, sharepoint, ssrs, subscription

We have a SSRS integrated inside a SharePoint farm. Recently we changed owner of all subscriptions to a different one (a technical account, 'ABC\XYZ'). The subscriptions target either a SharePoint library or a fileshare.

All the subscriptions are failing now with this error:

> Failure writing file : The permissions granted to user 'ABC\XYZ' are insufficient for performing this operation..

The account 'ABC\XYZ' has write access to the fileshare where the subscription is trying to save the data (checked with effective permissions). The account also has full control in the SharePoint website and also in the library (it inherits) where the subscription is trying to save the data.

What it might need more? Thanks for any tips!

We use SSRS 2016, SharePoint 2016.